# Group list of lxml elements by neighbouring attribute values

Tags: python

I have some html table rows like the following

```
<tr class="even"></tr>
<tr class="even"></tr>
<tr class="odd"></tr>
<tr class="odd"></tr>
<tr class="odd"></tr>
<tr class="even"></tr>
```

I get a list of tr elements using lxml:

```
trs = lxml.html.fromstring(html_str).xpath('//tr')
```

I would like to group together these tr elements into a list of lists:

```
[
 [<tr class="even">,<tr class="even">],
 [<tr class="odd">,<tr class="odd">,<tr class="odd">],
 [<tr class="even">]
]
```

That is, group neighbouring rows that have the same class together. So far I have implemented the following loop structure:

```
grouped, grp, last = [], [], trs[0].get('class')
for tr in trs:
    cl = tr.get('class')
    if last != cl:
        grouped.append(grp)
        grp = []
    grp.append(tr)
    last = cl
grouped.append(grp)
```

Is there a simple, elegant and pythonic way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the use of the `itertools.groupby` method would be somewhat nicer.

So, you could get the list of lists with your elements using:

```
from itertools import groupby

groupped = groupby(trs, key=lambda tag: tag.attrib.get('class'))

groups = []
for key, group in groupped:
    groups.append(list(group))
```